# How to limit only one pod for each available zones in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In my case there's a service that should be run only one instance in the zone. As an example, In my cluster There are 2 zones with 2 nodes for each. My service should be run on only one of nodes from the zone1 and only one of nodes from the zone2. Only one instance should be running in the zone. How i do it in k8s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pod Topology Spread Constraints https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use **anti-affinity** rules along with the node labels depending on the architecture and your application design.

Here's an example of the yaml file that you can use.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: name
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: name
  serviceName: name
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: name
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: key
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - value
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: ...
        imagePullPolicy: ...

---
```

For more information about anti-affinity, see this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#types-of-inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity).